# Org mode performance improvement tips

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am using org-mode extensively. I have lots of tables, and big source snippets with:

```
#+begin_src <whatever>
...
#+end_src
```

And also:

```
#+begin_example
...
#+end_example
```

I have noticed that, for big files (above 1000 lines?), performance is an issue: my emacs gets slow, and typing is not fluid anymore (the editor blocks for several milliseconds every so often).

This is the list of active minor modes `M-x describe-mode`):

```
Enabled minor modes: Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption Blink-Cursor
Column-Number Csv-Field-Index Delete-Selection Desktop-Save
Display-Time File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock Global-Font-Lock
Global-Whitespace Icomplete Ido-Everywhere Line-Number Mouse-Wheel
Recentf Server Shell-Dirtrack Show-Paren Tooltip Transient-Mark
Which-Function
```

I am not sure which mode is responsible for the bad performance, but I guess it is `org-mode`. Are there any configuration settings that I could tweak to make org-mode more performant?

Comment: the org mode list is a good place to ask this: http://news.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode

Comment: I agree with Tom: this is for the mailing list, definitively. The first question that'll be asked to you is to try to report the time spent in Org, thanks to the ELP (Emacs Lisp profiler) package. You can already search the mailing list for ELP...

Comment: If you highlight individual white spaces, that will cause a slow down -- `whitespace-style` with `spaces` = slow-down.  I use just the dots without color by removing `spaces` from `whitespace-style`.  `linum-mode` will also cause a slow-down in large files (in some major modes) -- it has a setting to not update so often, but that means the line numbers may not be correct until an update eventually occurs.  Try both of the above and see if that helps.

Comment: @lawlist: thank you very much! I will try those things. I hope that solves some performance issues that I am having with python buffers too. I'll report back